# Comparing all columns in file to reference column in same file

Tags: awk

I have a TAB file (SNPs file) in this format:

Location-->Reference sample-->sample1-->sample2-->sample3-->etc

```
Location        Reference      Sample1        Sample2       Sample3
1_56                T              A              G             C
1_226               A              A              C             G 
1_670               G              T              G             G
```

The goal is to created a loop where each sample value is compared to the reference value. If it does not match, I need to the line and column printed out for each sample. This is what I came up with:

```
awk '$2 != $3 &&  $3 != "." { print $1 $2 $3 }' ~FILEPATH/All_SNPs_annotated.txt >> sample1_SNPs_ready
```

The format this outputs is essentially a list of all the instance that column 3 does not match reference column and the location that do not match for a single sample like this:

```
LocationReferenceSample1
1_56TA
1_670GT

LocationReferenceSample2
1_56TG
1_226AC

LocationReferenceSample3
1_56TC
1_226AG
```

But each sample creates its own file.

The problem is I have to change the $3 value manually to move through the column- is there a way to do this so it loops through each column on it's own? This works if I have four samples however I now have 300+ which makes this a little unfeasible.

which gets me the columns I need. my hunch is that I need to create a loop that tells it to go through the columns and then in that loop add an awk command similar to above.

But this does not output a separate file for each sample.

I updated the information so hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: Could you please provide more clear(like mention all values which needs to be printed for mismatched ones) expected output in your question and let us know then. It will make question more clear.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I have added some more information so hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {
  split($0, names)
}
{
  for (s = 3; s <= NF; s++) {
    if ($s != $2 && $s != ".") {
      print $1 $2 $s > names[s]
    }
  }
}' file
```

```
$ tail -n +1 Sample*
==> Sample1 <==
LocationReferenceSample1
1_56TA
1_670GT

==> Sample2 <==
LocationReferenceSample2
1_56TG
1_226AC

==> Sample3 <==
LocationReferenceSample3
1_56TC
1_226AG
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! To go one step further, would it be possible to change the name of the output file to the column heading? ie; if 'sample1' was 'xxx' or 'rrr' would it be possible to make it that?